# Happiness + bewilderment =?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that combines *happiness* and *bewilderment*.

Say, A and B are long forgotten friends. After a long time B sends A very very good news. A is looking for a short message, a word that expresses his happiness and bewilderment in response to the news.

What would be the word combining these two — *happiness* and *bewilderment*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not one word, but the common expression *pleasantly surprised* comes to mind.

You might also consider *astonished*, although I think that connotes *amazement* rather than *happiness*.  It's still a positive word, though.  *Thrilled* is probably even better.

Comment: How about "thrilled" -- this seems to suggest both happiness and bewilderment, and is a little more intense than "pleasantly surprised."

Comment: @tchrist: fair enough; your point is well-taken, scandalous as it may be! My dictionary, under synonyms for _surprise_, mentions that to _astonish_ is "to strike with wonder by something unlooked for," so I suppose one could be astonished by a suprise visit, pleasant or unpleasant. But some added context from the O.P. would help – just what IS this "very very good news"? Are we talking about an impending last-minute visit, the announcement of an unplanned pregnancy, or a promising investment opportunity from a wealthy man in Nigeria?

Comment: @JAM: I agree; I think "thrilled" is a much better word than "astonished". I'll add it to my answer, but I won't restructure my original answer _too_ much, as tchrist's comment is simply too good for me to ruin the set-up.

Comment: Thrilled, bit cliche, but sounds right.

Answer (score 4):

Friend A could reply, "I am....:

> [Flabbergasted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flabbergasted) — overcome with astonishment; amazed; astounded
>
> [Thunderstruck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thunderstruck) — affected with sudden astonishment or amazement
>
> [Gobsmacked](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gobsmacked) — utterly astounded *(British slang)*
>
> [Floored](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/floored) — stunned; overwhelmed: *The very idea floored me.*

I think gobsmacked, even though I am in the U.S., is my favorite.

Comment: I'm very fond of "gobsmacked" and first thought to suggest it myself.  but it seems to have the same flexible connotation as "astonished."

Comment: @Bill Lefurgy, But it's such a fun word, that I think it is also carries a happier connotation.

Answer (score 4):

*Agog* might fit the bill.  [Thesaurus.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agog) shows it as a synonym for bewildered, ardent, eager, enthusiastic and breathless.

It’s used in the manner you seek in several examples. In  [From This Far Distant Shore](http://books.google.com/books?id=d8MzSzUkj8cC&lpg=RA1-PA38&dq=agog%20bewildered&pg=RA1-PA38#v=onepage&q=agog%20bewildered&f=false), Richard Curtin wrote “Transfixed by a prism of changing colors he gawks at the hypnotic pulse of alternating light.  Agog in pleasant bewilderment he follows the image waltzing to the tingling crystal spheres.” In  [Promises I Made My Mother](http://books.google.com/books?id=KeXe8UbXwuoC&lpg=PR21&dq=agog%20happy&pg=PR21#v=onepage&q=agog%20happy&f=false), Sam Haskell wrote “My father stood there agog, not quite believing his eyes, but happy for me.”  I will admit that the term can also sometimes be used in the same way as amazed – unpleasantly shocked – but [Common Phrases: And Where They Come From](http://books.google.com/books?id=sm0TCk5fSpYC&lpg=PA132&dq=agog%20happy&pg=PA132#v=onepage&q=agog%20happy&f=false) likens “all agog” to “Somebody eager, perhaps even ‘starry-eyed’ over a happy event.”  The term seems variously used as simply “agog” or amplified as “all agog.”

Answer (score 1):

Try

[astounded](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astounded) 
archaic 
: overwhelmed with astonishment or amazement

or

[floor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68832/happiness-bewilderment?rq=1)  b : flabbergast, dumbfound